# Retrieving form values in Master/Content pages

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

Form + element:

```
<form id="form" action="default.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" runat="server"/>
</form>
```

I am not able to retrieve form values by using the following code in Masterpages or Contentpages:

```
<% Response.Write(Request["submit"]); %>
```

The code-example above only works in independent .aspx pages.

---

Is it possible to retrieve form values in Masterpages or Contentpages in ASP.NET Webforms?

(I know about the built-in Webforms controls, but that is not the question/problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Request[submit.UniqueID]` this will avoid the hardcoded string and also will get the combined id of the control when rendered using master pages.  Hope this helps